# changing windows mobile 6.1 emulator screen resolution

Tags: windows-mobile

I am writing an app that should run on Omnia i900, and this device has different screen resolution from the mobile 6.1 emulator. It makes it very hard for me to create the forms right. It would really help if I could change the emulator to the right resolution. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Visual Studio:

- Click Options on the Visual Studio Tools menu
- Click Device Tools, and then click Devices.
- In the Devices box, select an emulator.
- When Emulation Startup Provider is displayed in the Startup server box, click Configure.
- Select the "Display" tab
- Adjust the screen dimensions as you wish.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Did you mean to choose the 'video' radio button instead of the 'Skin' button, and insert my exact pixels numbers? I tried it, but the emulator doesnt change...

Comment: I also had trouble getting this to work following ctacke's steps.  What got it to work for me was running the emulator then clicking File -> Clear Saved State then restarting the emulator again.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to change the resolution to a windows ce emulator. If you need to use another resolution, you should use a different emulator, For Example: Use the VGA emulator for (480 X 640).
find the emulator that works for you.